# SQL Select - Return same column twice based on IDs in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the tables below (`ID` & `ID2` are PK/FK respectively), how would I design a query which pulls out the `detailTable.name` column twice, once for each `ID` in the first table?

My desired result set would be something like:

```
+------+--------+------+---------+
| Name | Name 2 | Code | Created |
+------+--------+------+---------+
| Dave | Steven | AAAA | 1/10/10 |
+------+--------+------+---------+
```

I have tried doing this with two joins but keep getting this error:

```
SELECT 
       DT.name as [Name 1], 
       DT.name as [Name 2]
       --other columns would go here

FROM linkTable LT 

LEFT JOIN
     detailTable DT
     ON LT.id2 = DT.id 
LEFT JOIN
     linkTable LT2
     ON LT2.id = DT.id
where DT.id = '74'
```

**Error:** Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

linkTable

```
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| ID  | ID2   | Code   | Created                 | CreatedBy |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 76  | 15157 | AAAA   | 1/1/10                  | 844       |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 77  | 15340 | AAAA   | 2015-11-24 15:12:25.057 | 842       |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 94  | 14644 | GEOFA  | 2015-11-13 15:01:19.977 | 842       |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 94  | 16346 | XX2222 | 2015-11-13 15:01:57.290 | 842       |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
| 108 | 15966 | EMPE   | 2015-11-25 12:38:37.377 | 842       |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

detailTable

```
+-------+----------+
| ID    | Name     |
+-------+----------+
| 76    | Dave     |
+-------+----------+
| 15157 | Steven   |
+-------+----------+
| 94    | Roger    |
+-------+----------+
| 108   | Geoff    |
+-------+----------+
| 16346 | Penelope |
+-------+----------+
| 15966 | Paul     |
+-------+----------+
| 77    | Michael  |
+-------+----------+
| 14644 | Colin    |
+-------+----------+
| 15340 | Nigel    |
+-------+----------+
```

Thanks :)

Comment: All three ID columns are bigint

Comment: . . If all the id columns are numeric, I don't see how that error would occur.  The query clearly does not do what you intend, but that is a different issue.  Do you still get the same problem if you drop the single quotes from `'74'`?

Comment: I think the quotes were causing the problem, as well as joining the wrong tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, `left join` would not be needed, because the link table should only have valid references.  A tab points out, the logic is not correct in the original query.

My only guess is that the `'74'` is not really two digits -- hidden characters or some other problem.  In any case, single quotes are not needed for integer constants, so you can try:

```
SELECT DT1.name as [Name 1], 
       DT2.name as [Name 2]
       --other columns would go here
FROM linkTable LT JOIN
     detailTable DT1
     ON LT.id1 = DT1.id JOIN
     detailTable DT2
     ON LT.id2 = DT2.id
WHERE DT.id = 74;
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, I would question the assertion that all the id columns are `bigint`.  As written, the query has no other places where such a type conversion would be happening.

Comment: This was the correct answer - the quotes must have been causing the problem. Also I was joining the wrong table in my initial query. Now works as expected - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to join to the Detail table twice, not to the Link table:

```
SELECT 
       DT.name as [Name 1], 
       DT2.name as [Name 2]
       --other columns would go here

FROM linkTable LT 

LEFT JOIN
     detailTable DT
     ON LT.id = DT.id 
LEFT JOIN
     detailTable DT2
     ON LT.id2 = DT2.id
where LT.id = '74'
```

If you still get the conversion error with this format, it is probably in one of the "other columns" that you are not showing in your example.

Comment: This fixes the logical error.  Do you have an explanation of why the type error would occur?  The OP claims that all the id columns are numeric.  I don't see why this version would fix that problem.

Comment: Did you start to post this comment before my edit (below the code block)?   The type error could not possibly occur with the code the OP posted, if he is correct about the datatypes involved.